How to compile C++ modules project with CMake 3.28 in Mac
I have a simple program in CLion on Mac, which I am unable to compile with cmake version 3.28. When I switch to cmake version 3.27, everything just works fine.
How can I enable version 3.28? As per cmake website, the support for modules was added in 3.28. I am not even able to compile cpp files with cmake 3.28.
Here are the versions that I am using:
... ~ % cmake --version
cmake version 3.30.5

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
... ~ % g++ --version
g++-14 (Homebrew GCC 14.2.0) 14.2.0
Copyright (C) 2024 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

... ~ % 

Here is the code:
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

If I use the following CMakeLists.txt, everything works fine:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)
project(cpp)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)

add_executable(cpp main.cpp)

If I change the version to 3.28, everything breaks:
// CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)
project(cpp)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)

add_executable(cpp main.cpp)

Here is the error log:
====================[ Build | cpp | Debug ]=====================================
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/aarch64/bin/cmake --build /Users/aakashgupta/Documents/personal_finance/cpp/cmake-build-debug --target cpp -j 6
[0/1] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done (0.0s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/aakashgupta/Documents/personal_finance/cpp/cmake-build-debug
[2/4] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cpp.dir/main.cpp.o
FAILED: CMakeFiles/cpp.dir/main.cpp.o 
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.2.0/bin/g++-14   -g -std=gnu++23 -arch arm64 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk -fdiagnostics-color=always -MD -MT CMakeFiles/cpp.dir/main.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/cpp.dir/main.cpp.o.d -fmodules-ts -fmodule-mapper=CMakeFiles/cpp.dir/main.cpp.o.modmap -MD -fdeps-format=p1689r5 -x c++ -o CMakeFiles/cpp.dir/main.cpp.o -c /Users/aakashgupta/Documents/personal_finance/cpp/main.cpp
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/machine/_types.h:34,
                 from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:33,
                 from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27,
                 from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_wchar.h:70,
                 from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/wchar.h:67,
                 from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.2.0/include/c++/14/cwchar:44,
                 from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.2.0/include/c++/14/bits/postypes.h:40,
                 from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.2.0/include/c++/14/iosfwd:42,
                 from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.2.0/include/c++/14/ios:40,
                 from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.2.0/include/c++/14/ostream:40,
                 from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.2.0/include/c++/14/iostream:41,
                 from /Users/aakashgupta/Documents/personal_finance/cpp/main.cpp:1:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/arm/_types.h:75:9: error: 'ptrdiff_t' does not name a type
   75 | typedef ptrdiff_t               __darwin_ptrdiff_t;     /* ptr1 - ptr2 */
      |         ^~~~~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/arm/_types.h:20:1: note: 'ptrdiff_t' is defined in header '<cstddef>'; this is probably fixable by adding '#include <cstddef>'
   19 | #include <sys/_types/_wchar_t.h>
  +++ |+#include <cstddef>
   20 | #endif
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/arm/_types.h:85:9: error: 'size_t' does not name a type
   85 | typedef size_t                  __darwin_size_t;        /* sizeof() */
      |         ^~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/arm/_types.h:85:9: note: 'size_t' is defined in header '<cstddef>'; this is probably fixable by adding '#include <cstddef>'
In file included from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.2.0/lib/gcc/current/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin24/14/include-fixed/stdio.h:75,
                 from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_wchar.h:90:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:245:1: error: 'size_t' does not name a type
  245 | size_t   fread(void * __restrict __ptr, size_t __size, size_t __nitems, FILE * __restrict __stream);
      | ^~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:162:1: note: 'size_t' is defined in header '<cstddef>'; this is probably fixable by adding '#include <cstddef>'
  161 | #include <sys/_types/_seek_set.h>
  +++ |+#include <cstddef>
  162 | 
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:252:1: error: 'size_t' does not name a type
  252 | size_t   fwrite(const void * __restrict __ptr, size_t __size, size_t __nitems, FILE * __restrict __stream) __DARWIN_ALIAS(fwrite);
      | ^~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:252:1: note: 'size_t' is defined in header '<cstddef>'; this is probably fixable by adding '#include <cstddef>'
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:270:61: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
  270 | int      setvbuf(FILE * __restrict, char * __restrict, int, size_t);
      |                                                             ^~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:431:44: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
  431 | int      snprintf(char * __restrict __str, size_t __size, const char * __restrict __format, ...) __printflike(3, 4);
      |                                            ^~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:434:45: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
  434 | int      vsnprintf(char * __restrict __str, size_t __size, const char * __restrict __format, va_list) __printflike(3, 0);
      |                                             ^~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:451:46: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
  451 | ssize_t getdelim(char ** __restrict __linep, size_t * __restrict __linecapp, int __delimiter, FILE * __restrict __stream) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_7, __IPHONE_4_3);
      |                                              ^~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:452:45: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
  452 | ssize_t getline(char ** __restrict __linep, size_t * __restrict __linecapp, FILE * __restrict __stream) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_7, __IPHONE_4_3);
      |                                             ^~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:453:41: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
  453 | FILE *fmemopen(void * __restrict __buf, size_t __size, const char * __restrict __mode) __API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.13), ios(11.0), tvos(11.0), watchos(4.0));
      |                                         ^~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:454:37: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
  454 | FILE *open_memstream(char **__bufp, size_t *__sizep) __API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.13), ios(11.0), tvos(11.0), watchos(4.0));
      |                                     ^~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:469:25: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
  469 | char    *fgetln(FILE *, size_t *);
      |                         ^~~~~~
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/time.h:63,
                 from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_wchar.h:91:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_time.h:116:1: error: 'size_t' does not name a type
  116 | size_t strftime(char * __restrict, size_t, const char * __restrict, const struct tm * __restrict) __DARWIN_ALIAS(strftime);
      | ^~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_time.h:74:1: note: 'size_t' is defined in header '<cstddef>'; this is probably fixable by adding '#include <cstddef>'
   73 | #include <sys/_types/_timespec.h>
  +++ |+#include <cstddef>
   74 | 
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_ctype.h:71,
                 from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/ctype.h:66,
                 from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/___wctype.h:72,
                 from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/__wctype.h:39,
                 from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_wchar.h:92:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/runetype.h:81:53: error: '__darwin_size_t' has not been declared
   81 |         __darwin_rune_t (*__sgetrune)(const char *, __darwin_size_t, char const **);
      |                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/runetype.h:82:64: error: '__darwin_size_t' has not been declared
   82 |         int             (*__sputrune)(__darwin_rune_t, char *, __darwin_size_t, char **);
      |                                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_wchar.h:107:1: error: 'size_t' does not name a type
  107 | size_t  mbrlen(const char * __restrict, size_t, mbstate_t * __restrict);
      | ^~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_wchar.h:93:1: note: 'size_t' is defined in header '<cstddef>'; this is probably fixable by adding '#include <cstddef>'
   92 | #include <__wctype.h>
  +++ |+#include <cstddef>
   93 | 
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_wchar.h:108:1: error: 'size_t' does not name a type
  108 | size_t  mbrtowc(wchar_t * __restrict, const char * __restrict, size_t,
      | ^~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_wchar.h:108:1: note: 'size_t' is defined in header '<cstddef>'; this is probably fixable by adding '#include <cstddef>'
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_wchar.h:111:1: error: 'size_t' does not name a type
  111 | size_t  mbsrtowcs(wchar_t * __restrict, const char ** __restrict, size_t,
      | ^~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_wchar.h:111:1: note: 'size_t' is defined in header '<cstddef>'; this is probably fixable by adding '#include <cstddef>'
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_wchar.h:115:40: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
  115 | int     swprintf(wchar_t * __restrict, size_t, const wchar_t * __restrict, ...);
      |                                        ^~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_wchar.h:120:41: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
  120 | int     vswprintf(wchar_t * __restrict, size_t, const wchar_t * __restrict,
      |                                         ^~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_wchar.h:123:1: error: 'size_t' does not name a type
  123 | size_t  wcrtomb(char * __restrict, wchar_t, mbstate_t * __restrict);
      | ^~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_wchar.h:123:1: note: 'size_t' is defined in header '<cstddef>'; this is probably fixable by adding '#include <cstddef>'
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_wchar.h:129:1: error: 'size_t' does not name a type
  129 | size_t  wcscspn(const wchar_t *, const wchar_t *);
      | ^~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_wchar.h:129:1: note: 'size_t' is defined in header '<cstddef>'; this is probably fixable by adding '#include <cstddef>'
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_wchar.h:130:1: error: 'size_t' does not name a type
  130 | size_t  wcsftime(wchar_t * __restrict, size_t, const wchar_t * __restrict,
      | ^~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_wchar.h:130:1: note: 'size_t' is defined in header '<cstddef>'; this is probably fixable by adding '#include <cstddef>'
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_wchar.h:132:1: error: 'size_t' does not name a type
  132 | size_t  wcslen(const wchar_t *);
      | ^~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_wchar.h:132:1: note: 'size_t' is defined in header '<cstddef>'; this is probably fixable by adding '#include <cstddef>'
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_wchar.h:133:68: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
  133 | wchar_t *wcsncat(wchar_t * __restrict, const wchar_t * __restrict, size_t);
      |                                                                    ^~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_wchar.h:134:51: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
  134 | int     wcsncmp(const wchar_t *, const wchar_t *, size_t);
      |                                                   ^~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_wchar.h:135:69: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
  135 | wchar_t *wcsncpy(wchar_t * __restrict , const wchar_t * __restrict, size_t);
      |                                                                     ^~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_wchar.h:138:1: error: 'size_t' does not name a type
  138 | size_t  wcsrtombs(char * __restrict, const wchar_t ** __restrict, size_t,
      | ^~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_wchar.h:138:1: note: 'size_t' is defined in header '<cstddef>'; this is probably fixable by adding '#include <cstddef>'
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_wchar.h:140:1: error: 'size_t' does not name a type
  140 | size_t  wcsspn(const wchar_t *, const wchar_t *);
      | ^~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_wchar.h:140:1: note: 'size_t' is defined in header '<cstddef>'; this is probably fixable by adding '#include <cstddef>'
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_wchar.h:142:1: error: 'size_t' does not name a type
  142 | size_t  wcsxfrm(wchar_t * __restrict, const wchar_t * __restrict, size_t);
      | ^~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_wchar.h:142:1: note: 'size_t' is defined in header '<cstddef>'; this is probably fixable by adding '#include <cstddef>'
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_wchar.h:150:44: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
  150 | wchar_t *wmemchr(const wchar_t *, wchar_t, size_t);
      |                                            ^~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_wchar.h:151:51: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
  151 | int     wmemcmp(const wchar_t *, const wchar_t *, size_t);
      |                                                   ^~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_wchar.h:152:68: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
  152 | wchar_t *wmemcpy(wchar_t * __restrict, const wchar_t * __restrict, size_t);
      |                                                                    ^~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_wchar.h:153:47: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
  153 | wchar_t *wmemmove(wchar_t *, const wchar_t *, size_t);
      |                                               ^~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_wchar.h:154:38: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
  154 | wchar_t *wmemset(wchar_t *, wchar_t, size_t);
      |                                      ^~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_wchar.h:157:35: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
  157 | int     wcswidth(const wchar_t *, size_t);
      |                                   ^~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_wchar.h:195:1: error: 'size_t' does not name a type
  195 | size_t  mbsnrtowcs(wchar_t * __restrict, const char ** __restrict, size_t,
      | ^~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_wchar.h:195:1: note: 'size_t' is defined in header '<cstddef>'; this is probably fixable by adding '#include <cstddef>'
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_wchar.h:198:68: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
  198 | wchar_t *wcpncpy(wchar_t * __restrict, const wchar_t * __restrict, size_t) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_7, __IPHONE_4_3);
      |                                                                    ^~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_wchar.h:201:55: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
  201 | int     wcsncasecmp(const wchar_t *, const wchar_t *, size_t n) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_7, __IPHONE_4_3);
      |                                                       ^~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_wchar.h:202:1: error: 'size_t' does not name a type
  202 | size_t  wcsnlen(const wchar_t *, size_t) __pure __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_7, __IPHONE_4_3);
      | ^~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_wchar.h:202:1: note: 'size_t' is defined in header '<cstddef>'; this is probably fixable by adding '#include <cstddef>'
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_wchar.h:203:1: error: 'size_t' does not name a type
  203 | size_t  wcsnrtombs(char * __restrict, const wchar_t ** __restrict, size_t,
      | ^~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_wchar.h:203:1: note: 'size_t' is defined in header '<cstddef>'; this is probably fixable by adding '#include <cstddef>'
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_wchar.h:205:42: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
  205 | FILE *open_wmemstream(wchar_t ** __bufp, size_t * __sizep) __API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.13), ios(11.0), tvos(11.0), watchos(4.0));
      |                                          ^~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_wchar.h:215:37: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
  215 | wchar_t *fgetwln(FILE * __restrict, size_t *) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_7, __IPHONE_4_3);
      |                                     ^~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_wchar.h:216:1: error: 'size_t' does not name a type
  216 | size_t  wcslcat(wchar_t *, const wchar_t *, size_t);
      | ^~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_wchar.h:216:1: note: 'size_t' is defined in header '<cstddef>'; this is probably fixable by adding '#include <cstddef>'
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_wchar.h:217:1: error: 'size_t' does not name a type
  217 | size_t  wcslcpy(wchar_t *, const wchar_t *, size_t);
      | ^~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/_wchar.h:217:1: note: 'size_t' is defined in header '<cstddef>'; this is probably fixable by adding '#include <cstddef>'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.2.0/include/c++/14/cwchar:153:11: error: 'mbrlen' has not been declared in '::'
  153 |   using ::mbrlen;
      |           ^~~~~~
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.2.0/include/c++/14/cwchar:154:11: error: 'mbrtowc' has not been declared in '::'
  154 |   using ::mbrtowc;
      |           ^~~~~~~
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.2.0/include/c++/14/cwchar:156:11: error: 'mbsrtowcs' has not been declared in '::'
  156 |   using ::mbsrtowcs;
      |           ^~~~~~~~~
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.2.0/include/c++/14/cwchar:178:11: error: 'wcrtomb' has not been declared in '::'
  178 |   using ::wcrtomb;
      |           ^~~~~~~
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.2.0/include/c++/14/cwchar:183:11: error: 'wcscspn' has not been declared in '::'
  183 |   using ::wcscspn;
      |           ^~~~~~~
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.2.0/include/c++/14/cwchar:184:11: error: 'wcsftime' has not been declared in '::'
  184 |   using ::wcsftime;
      |           ^~~~~~~~
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.2.0/include/c++/14/cwchar:185:11: error: 'wcslen' has not been declared in '::'
  185 |   using ::wcslen;
      |           ^~~~~~
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.2.0/include/c++/14/cwchar:189:11: error: 'wcsrtombs' has not been declared in '::'
  189 |   using ::wcsrtombs;
      |           ^~~~~~~~~
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.2.0/include/c++/14/cwchar:190:11: error: 'wcsspn' has not been declared in '::'
  190 |   using ::wcsspn;
      |           ^~~~~~
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.2.0/include/c++/14/cwchar:198:11: error: 'wcsxfrm' has not been declared in '::'
  198 |   using ::wcsxfrm;
      |           ^~~~~~~
In file included from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.2.0/include/c++/14/bits/exception_ptr.h:36,
                 from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.2.0/include/c++/14/exception:166,
                 from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.2.0/include/c++/14/ios:41:
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.2.0/include/c++/14/bits/cxxabi_init_exception.h:63:32: error: 'size_t' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'std::size_t'?
   63 |       __cxa_allocate_exception(size_t) _GLIBCXX_NOTHROW;
      |                                ^~~~~~
      |                                std::size_t
In file included from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.2.0/include/c++/14/bits/requires_hosted.h:31,
                 from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.2.0/include/c++/14/iostream:38:
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.2.0/include/c++/14/aarch64-apple-darwin24/bits/c++config.h:310:33: note: 'std::size_t' declared here
  310 |   typedef __SIZE_TYPE__         size_t;
      |                                 ^~~~~~
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.2.0/include/c++/14/bits/exception_ptr.h: In function 'std::__exception_ptr::exception_ptr std::make_exception_ptr(_Ex)':
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.2.0/include/c++/14/bits/exception_ptr.h:253:55: error: '__cxxabiv1::__cxa_allocate_exception' cannot be used as a function
  253 |       void* __e = __cxxabiv1::__cxa_allocate_exception(sizeof(_Ex));
      |                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.2.0/include/c++/14/ios:42:
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.2.0/include/c++/14/bits/char_traits.h: In static member function 'static constexpr std::size_t std::char_traits<wchar_t>::length(const char_type*)':
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.2.0/include/c++/14/bits/char_traits.h:522:16: error: 'wcslen' was not declared in this scope
  522 |         return wcslen(__s);
      |                ^~~~~~
In file included from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.2.0/include/c++/14/aarch64-apple-darwin24/bits/gthr-default.h:35,
                 from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.2.0/include/c++/14/aarch64-apple-darwin24/bits/gthr.h:157,
                 from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.2.0/include/c++/14/ext/atomicity.h:35,
                 from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.2.0/include/c++/14/bits/ios_base.h:39,
                 from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.2.0/include/c++/14/ios:44:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/pthread.h: At global scope:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/pthread.h:236:66: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
  236 | int pthread_attr_getguardsize(const pthread_attr_t * __restrict, size_t * __restrict);
      |                                                                  ^~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/pthread.h:253:57: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
  253 |                 void * _Nullable * _Nonnull __restrict, size_t * __restrict);
      |                                                         ^~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/pthread.h:260:66: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
  260 | int pthread_attr_getstacksize(const pthread_attr_t * __restrict, size_t * __restrict);
      |                                                                  ^~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/pthread.h:269:49: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
  269 | int pthread_attr_setguardsize(pthread_attr_t *, size_t);
      |                                                 ^~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/pthread.h:285:53: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
  285 | int pthread_attr_setstack(pthread_attr_t *, void *, size_t);
      |                                                     ^~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/pthread.h:291:49: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
  291 | int pthread_attr_setstacksize(pthread_attr_t *, size_t);
      |                                                 ^~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/pthread.h:531:44: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
  531 | int     pthread_getname_np(pthread_t,char*,size_t);
      |                                            ^~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/pthread.h:546:1: error: 'size_t' does not name a type
  546 | size_t pthread_get_stacksize_np(pthread_t);
      | ^~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/pthread.h:76:1: note: 'size_t' is defined in header '<cstddef>'; this is probably fixable by adding '#include <cstddef>'
   75 | #include <sys/_types/_sigset_t.h>
  +++ |+#include <cstddef>
   76 | 
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/pthread.h:746:23: error: 'size_t' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'std::size_t'?
  746 | pthread_cpu_number_np(size_t *cpu_number_out);
      |                       ^~~~~~
      |                       std::size_t
...
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.


What if you just execute this command directly: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.2.0/bin/g++-14   -g -std=gnu++23 -arch arm64 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk -fdiagnostics-color=always -MD -MT CMakeFiles/cpp.dir/main.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/cpp.dir/main.cpp.o.d -fmodules-ts -fmodule-mapper=CMakeFiles/cpp.dir/main.cpp.o.modmap -MD -fdeps-format=p1689r5 -x c++ -o CMakeFiles/cpp.dir/main.cpp.o -c /Users/aakashgupta/Documents/personal_finance/cpp/main.cpp? It sounds like compiler issue. not cmake.

You're using cmake 3.30 as well. Did you actually update your cmake, or just change the minimum version? The minimum version doesn't actually change what's being used.

I only changed the minimum version, nothing else.

The above command is giving same error. I am not sure what is the right command to execute with my g++ installation... I want to use C++ 20 modules, and I am unable to find anything that gives a minimal module based "hello world" project in CLion on Mac

What compiler and what version of it are you using? Does it support modules? Does your CMake know it supports modules?

Can you compare the created command calling the compiler for the different require minimum CMake versions?

Try to add this line in your CMakeLists.txt:
add_compile_options(-include cstddef)

or manually include cstddef:
#include <cstddef>

